# unable to set django model values

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have below code

```
exinfo = ExistingCardInfo.objects.filter(CustID=custid)   
trail4 = exinfo[0].trail4
logger.debug(exinfo[0].trail4) # prints 1984
exinfo[0].trail4=3000
logger.debug(exinfo[0].trail4) # again prints 1984
```

Initially trail4 value is 1984. After I set trail4 value to 3000, i'm still getting 1984.
Is there anything wrong with above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indexing a queryset reruns the query. Extract the single model, modify the field, *save* the model, then reindex.

Comment: Is this something related to Django upgrade? Because it was working in Django 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

I've experience something similar to you, when trying to assign values to a queryset property when accessing them through an index.

Can you try something like:

```
excardinfo = exinfo[0]
excardinfo.trail4 = 3000
excardinfo.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

As some of the other answers have said, indexing a queryset causes django to hit the database again.

If you don't want to save the changes to the database (in which case, you wouldn't want to use .save()), then extract that model and save it to a variable:

```
thismodel = exinfo[0]
print thismodel.trail4
thismodel.trail4 = 3000
print thismodel.trail4
```

The above will print 1984 and 3000. It will not save to database, so the row stored in the database remains unaltered.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @dm03514 what you get after filter is just queryset whatever changes you make in it are not reflected in the database.
To reflect changes in the database use .save() function on the object.